# Can the Connections 6 Search Sidebar be integrated into third party apps?

Tags: ibm-connections

IBM Connections 6.0 introduced a new floating button for opening a panel for quickly searching for content in IBM Connections.
[image: IBM Connections Search Sidebar]

Is there any documentation or known way of adding this button and panel to third party Connections applications?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: We didn't find an officially supported way, but do have it working in Kudos Boards. We extended our Connections header integration to also load the search side panel. Our method involves fetching `/homepage/web/pageHeader` parsing it as DOM and picking out the elements, scripts and css needed and adding them to our page.